# How to repeat a code block in PHP with no function to keep the context?

Tags: php

Lets imagine I have form, and for some conditions I have to set the same variables:

(Edit: This is not a real code, it is an example to show my point)

```
if($_GET['a']==1){
    $case="A";
    $con->query("UPDATE table SET done=1;");
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
    echo "Process is done with result: $b";
}
if($_GET['b']==2){
    $action="A";
    $con->query("INSERT INTO table (done) VALUES (0);");
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
    echo "Process has been added";
    $proc+=$b;
}
if($_GET['a']==$_GET['b']){
    $action="D";
    $con->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$_GET[id];");
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
    echo "Process $_GET[id] has been deleted";
    $proc-=$b;
}
if(!isset($_GET['b'])){
    $case="D";
    $con->query("UPDATE table SET done=0;");
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
    echo "Process is undone with result: 0";
}
```

As you can see, all these conditions repeat the same 4 lines:

```
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
```

but I can not replace these 4 lines with functions because I need to set these 4 variables in this same context, I can not use a big `if(condition1 or condition2 or ...)` statement because some lines (at the begining and at the end) are different.

My best approach is replace these 4 lines with `include('my4lines.php');`, where my4lines.php is a file containing those 4 lines.

What is the best way to repeat this code?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code `DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$_GET[id];` is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: `$refresh_page=1;
    $a=$_GET['a'];` could be moved to before the first `if` (and removed from within all the `if` blocks) without any consequences as far as I can see. The more morph_a2b line is tricker because it depends on the value of $case which is set differently each time (although in the `if($_GET['a']==$_GET['b']){` section, $case is undefined, I don't know if that's intentional). Clearly `$_GET['b']=0;` is also a problem because the later `if`s rely on its value.

Comment: Having said that, putting those two lines outside all the `ifs` would only potentially be an issue if none of the `if`s are entered in any circumstance. So maybe it's a problem for those values to be set in that scenario? Since we don't know what you do with those variables later, it's impossible to make a full impact assessment.

Comment: [It's a bit whiffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - I just get the feeling that there's something more *wrong* here; it feels like this script is trying to do too much, with too many conditionals and it's heading dangerously into spaghetti territory... it *might* be worth taking a step back and trying to think of a different approach rather than marching determinedly forward on the wrong track.

Comment: I should clarify this is not the real code, it is an intentional spaghetti example to show my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function and pass the parameter as reference, this will solve your same context issue.

```php
function aFunction(&$refresh_page, &$a, &$b, &$case){
    $refresh_page=1;
    $_GET['b']=0;
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    $b=morph_a2b($_GET['a'],$case);
}

if($_GET['a']==1){
    $case="A";
    $con->query("UPDATE table SET done=1;");
    aFunction($refresh_page,$a,$b,$case);
    echo "Process is done with result: $b";
}
if($_GET['b']==2){
    $action="A";
    $con->query("INSERT INTO table (done) VALUES (0);");
    aFunction($refresh_page,$a,$b,$case);
    echo "Process has been added";
    $proc+=$b;
}
if($_GET['a']==$_GET['b']){
    $action="D";
    $con->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$_GET[id];");
    aFunction($refresh_page,$a,$b,$case);
    echo "Process $_GET[id] has been deleted";
    $proc-=$b;
}
if(!isset($_GET['b'])){
    $case="D";
    $con->query("UPDATE table SET done=0;");
    aFunction($refresh_page,$a,$b,$case);
    echo "Process is undone with result: 0";
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that I can do that! it's a beautiful solution, thank you, for people having this issue and wanting to know more about it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php